# Share root level site in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, share

I am having root site for my Web Application and i want to share this root site with the users in my Active Directory without adding them in my **Site Collection Administration**.

I tried using "Share" option in the top ribbon but all the time i am getting the message

> **Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.**

Am i missing something?

My working environment is SharePoint 2013 On Premises.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you a site collection administrator?

Comment: Yes. I am logged in as site collection administration

Comment: You should not get such kind of error.. Please check these articles..http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sharing-in-sharepoint-2013-1


http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/11/11/all-you-need-to-know-about-sharing-in-sharepoint-2013-2/

Comment: i have also tried this at my SharePoint environment it is working fine.Please have a look on your configuration

Comment: Looking for that only , In another server it is working fine. As per @Hardik's suggestion I tried to verify on different server there it was working fine, so i guess it may be due to improper configuration of users in AD.

Comment: If it is fine than please mark the answer so others can get benefit of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add yourself through Application Mangement > Manage Applications > User Policy**

> Try creating a permission policy for your web application on Central
>   Administration followingly:
>
> 1. On Central Administration, navigate to Application Management -> Under Web Applications: Manage web applications
> 2. Select your My Site -web application by clicking it, and open Permission Policy
> 3. Click Add Permission Policy Level
> 4. Enter at least the Name for your Permission Policy
> 5. Select following Permissions:
> 6. Create Subsites - Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and Document Workspace sites.
> 7. View Pages - View pages in a Web site.
> 8. Browse User Information - View information about users of the Web site.
> 9. Open - Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.
> 10. Leave other parts unmarket and click Save
> 11. Make sure your My Site -web application is selected and open User Policy
> 12. Click Add Users, and on first view leave Zones: (All zones) selected, then click Next >
> 13. On Choose Users -part click Browse (the catalogue type of icon). Click All Users and select Everyone activated. Press Add -> and OK
> 14. On Choose Permissions, select the Permission Policy you recently created, and finally click Finish